# System padding on Huawei devices when used Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, huawei-developers, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

After refactoring old solution my QA found problem with bottom navigation and modalbottomsheetdialog below him on Huawei devices also the dialog is shifted down, i dont know how fix this, because on Pixel 7, Samsung A13, emulator - all perfect, but on huawei i get this result.
Current settings for paddings:

```
Scaffold(
...
     },
        contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0,0,0,0)
    ) { localPadding ->
        NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(paddingValues = localPadding)
                .consumeWindowInsets(paddingValues = localPadding)
                .windowInsetsPadding(
                    WindowInsets.safeDrawing.only(
                        WindowInsetsSides.Horizontal,
                    ),
                )
                .systemBarsPadding(),
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = startDestination
        ) {
...
```

[huawei device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLMRG.png)
[Samsung A13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3htDj.png)

[Top dialog on huawei](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35EoJ.png)
[Top dialog on A13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jc6h.png)

Somebody knowns what's main problem of this behavior, or had similar problem. How you fix this in your app?

Update from 1 December, 2023:

On current time i'm use Compose BOM: 2023.10.01 and for currect usage bottomSheet, i should do this:

```
ModalBottomSheet(
   modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
   sheetState = sheetState,
   onDismissRequest = { },
   windowInsets = WindowInsets.ime
       .union(WindowInsets.statusBars)
       .union(WindowInsets.navigationBars)
) { 
  // content here
}
```

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm facing the same issue with dialogs

Comment: @liltof Hi, please check update. On current time i'm don't know how do better.